# how to bend a rectangular png onto a circular on iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, png, geometry

I have created a .png image by code; the .png is rectangular in shape and I want to create a circular shaped .png as if I'm able to have the 2 smaller sides of the rect join.
I was thinking to use bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise: but then how to draw the image on top of it?
 any help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean that you want to stretch the rectangle around a path so that the two shorter sides meet and make an annulus? (IE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics) )

Comment: Yes, but no idea how to achieve this; I'm quite new to programmatically modify graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it would have been a job for Core Image (specifically the filter CICircularWrap), but that is unfortunately *not available* on iOS.

More in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CICircularWrap), for people interested anyway, or working on OS X.

Comment: True, my bad. It was in the iOS Developer Library, but still OS X only. OP could file a bug report to have the filter implemented on iOS, too...

Comment: Don't feel too bad, I only looked because I Had No Idea (tm) that things like that were supported and I am in the process of learning all sorts of things about iOS.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for...but it's missing in iOS

Answer (score 0):

This may not be at all what you're looking for (it could be though...), but if you simply want your image to appear in a circle, IF your image is square, you can fake a circle using layer tricks, like so:

```
image.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.size.height / 2;
image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

That is, make the corner radius half the height and you can turn a square into a circle. :-)

To better define the circle, you can easily add a border:

```
image.layer.borderWidth = 2;
image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor black].CGColor;
```

Now, be careful about doing this sort of thing in `UITableViewCell`'s because performance of the table can suffer. But generally speaking, these simple techniques can add a lot of UI interest with little effort.

Comment: unfortunately I'm looking for bending a rect, wrapping it in a circle;